# Communications link failure "The last packet sent successfully to the server was 37 milliseconds ago."

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I had to reinstall MySQL completely because everything was broken and I wanted to set it up clean again. Now I get the following error when I run my application that worked with the previously set up mysql database:

```
om.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure The last packet successfully received from the server was 38 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 37 milliseconds ago.
```

I have a java application that connects to the mysql database like this:

```
 static Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        String username = "root";
        String password = "password";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/wnetwork?user=" + username + "&password=" + password;
        try{
            setConnection(DriverManager.getConnection(url));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
        return connection;
    }
```

I also tried it with the username and password outside the jdbc url.
The MySQL instance is running, I can connect to it in the terminal and everything else works perfectly fine (as far as I know).

Comment: The poor coding is not going to help you. If your *global* (bad idea) `Connection` object has *already* been assigned, that code will go about getting it and setting it all over again anyway. You should be checking if you *already* have a valid connection. Come back again with reworked code (posted into the question) showing that you still have a problem

Comment: Also, you should be using the three argument `DriverManager.getConnection` method, not passing the credentials in the connection string

Comment: As you can see in my question I had the three argument `DriverManager.getConnection`method before. Also the code i provided worked as is before when i had my old mysql installation

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/wnetwork?user=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&useSSL=false";
```

Just add string: `&useSSL=false`